# Displaying linked information based on a users profile fields

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, users

I am trying to figure out the best way to show certain information based on a users profile field.

What I am trying to achieve is having a directory of peoples contact information (name, email, phone number) - note these will not be users in the drupal system.

Then for example when creating a drupal user, one of the required fields will be contact - in this field I would like to have it select a contact name from the directory I mentioned above.

If the person was not in the contact information then, the administrator would have the option to create the new contact before finishing the drupal user signup.

Finally once the contact field is linked to a persons name in the contact information, I would like to have a node that looks at the drupal users profile, shows their information and shows the contact information that is linked.

I hope the above makes sense :)

The way I think I would approach it is by creating a custom content type for the contact information directory with a name, email and phone number field.

Then adding a contact field to the users profiles (not sure how to link to the contact content type though - maybe through taxonomy?) - I am not sure how I would go about creating a new contact during a user signup?

Lastly displaying the information, assuming I could link the contact field to the relevant information I am guessing that using views and it's filters would be the best way to display it.

Any thoughts or guidance on this would be appreciated :)

Comment: I think you are heading the right direction. You can add an entity reference field in the profile pointing to the content type of the contact information.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I have managed to partially get what I am after using the Entity Reference node, which at the moment renders the relevant node information.  Just going to start digging into views to see if I can get some more control over the fields.

Comment: good to know that it helped :-)